# How to connect the QuickBooks (QODBC) data through Pentaho (Kettle) for ETL?

Tags: pentaho, quickbooks, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, qodbc

I am trying to connect the QuickBooks (QODBC) application data through Pentaho (Kettle) for ETL process. Would like to know how can we connect the QuickBooks (QODBC) application data through Pentaho.

Answer (score 1):

Pentaho's ODBC connections use the JDBC-ODBC bridge that is bundled with Java.

The JDBC-ODBC bridge driver was removed in Java 8, preventing ODBC drivers from being usable in newer versions of Pentaho or other Java-based applications.

Generally, in such scenario, we suggest to use MS-Access (third Party application -->MS Access--> Linked tables-->QRemote-->QODBC-->QuickBooks Data), but in this case, accessing MS-Access also requires OBDC. A JDBC driver called UCanAccess is available as an alternative.
The limitation of UCanAccess is that it does not allow to query linked table and can only connect to ms-access base tables.

I would suggest to get in touch with Pentaho and see if you can get a version that allows JDBC-ODBC connection (Generic ODBC) via DSN.

Comment: Hi Raj, Thank you for the reply. I can connect the QuickBooks DSN (QuickBooks Data 64-Bit QRemote) through Pentaho using the Java 7, and the connection is succeeded. However, When I try view the data from QuickBooks through Pentaho spoon, Its not producing anything.  Getting the following error " [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver does not support this function" . Do you have any idea on this. And also, Does the MS access file always be updated when we add the data in QuickBooks. I am planning to read the QB data through MS access using Pentaho

Comment: Hi Raj. If you'd like to add information about your company or job title, it would be best to add that in your profile. We prefer posts to be uncluttered here. The only time where it is a good idea to mention you work for company is if you are recommending a product or service that you have a financial incentive in.

Comment: Rajasekaran, are you using MS access as a middleware?, which DSN are you using for the connection, QuickBooks Data, QuickBooks Data QRemote or any other?  I would suggest opening a support ticket at http://support.qodbc.com